# Index-variable as an independent variable

Tags: regression, missing-data, predictor

In my regression on gdp-growth, I also want to bring in something like a "freedom"-variable, to show how free a country is (press freedom, economic freedom). now there is no number for this, except some indices like for example the economic freedom index. is it now possible to put in a "index"-outcome per country in a regression, as an independent variable (f.e: cuba has a 29.6 and switzerland has a 80.6)? or should i just make a dummy variable out of it free/not free? what other options would I have?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you wish to analyse the data and interpret the results. However, I would say using a Boolean 'freedom' variable is not a good idea here - how are you going to decide what constitutes a free country?

I'm not entirely sure how the 'freedom score' is generated or should be interpreted, but if you do, then that seems a sensible variable to use. Another option might be just to use the rank of the country, this has the advantage of being easy to interpret, although you would need to account for countries with no data (or just exclude them entirely).

Comment: ok. the economic freedom index of the Heritage Foundation is in my opinion a good indicator for this factor. it measures freedom through these characteristics:  

-Rule of Law (property rights, freedom from corruption);
- Limited Government (fiscal freedom, government spending);
- Regulatory Efficiency (business freedom, labor freedom, monetary freedom)
- Open Markets (trade freedom, investment freedom, financial freedom)

isnt that represantative enough?